# How to load .html file from embedded resources by web browser in visual basic 2010

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Visual Basic 2010

I try this

myWebBrowser1.Navigate(My.Resources.HomePage)

but it fail to execute
it show "Value does not fall within the expected range."

PS : HomePage is a .html file, I add it to the project resources.(embedded)

Please help me ~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

**VB code:**

```
Private Sub DisplayHtml()
  Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
  Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Write(String.Empty)
  Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources._Readme
End Sub
```

you can use this as reference to your problem:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/08/15/displaying-custom-html-in-webbrowser-control.aspx

Comment: @AnsonTan : Please mark my answer as **correct** if it's useful so others knew it.

Comment: I would love to write an infinite amount of thank you's right now ;D